# LSTM value error connected to the initializer

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I am using Keras to built a LSTM model.

```
 def LSTM_model_1(X_train,Y_train,Dropout,hidden_units):
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Masking(mask_value=666, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
   model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, dropout=Dropout))   
   model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences=True))
   model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences=True))
   model.add(Dense(Y_train.shape[-1], activation='softmax'))

   model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam',metrics['categorical_accuracy'])

   return model
```

The input data is of shape
X_train.shape=(77,100,34); Y_Train.shape=(77,100,7)

The Y data is one-hot-encoded. Both input tensors are zero-padded for the last list entry. The padded values in Y_train is 0. So no state gets a value of 1 for the padded end. dropout=0 and hidden_units=2 which seems not related to the following error.

Unfortunately, I get following error which I think is connected with the shape of Y. But I cannot put my finger on it. The error happens when the first LSTM layer is initialized/added.

> ValueError: Initializer for variable lstm_58/kernel/ is from inside a
>   control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a
>   variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the
>   initializer.

If I follow the error I noticed that it comes down to this:

> dtype: If set, initial_value will be converted to the given type.
>           If `None`, either the datatype will be kept (if `initial_value` is
>           a Tensor), or `convert_to_tensor` will decide.

"convert to tensor' creates an object which is then None and leads to the error. Apparently, the LSTM tries to convert the input into a tensor... But if I look at my input, it is already a tensor.

Does any of you have an idea what went wrong or how to use lambda as an initializer? Thanks

EDit: the stack trace

> File "C:\Users\310122653\Documents\GitHub\DNN\build_model.py", line
>   44, in LSTM_model_1
>       model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, activation='tanh', return_sequences=True, dropout=Dropout))
>
> File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py",
>   line 492, in add
>       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py",
>   line 499, in **call**
>       return super(RNN, self).**call**(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py",
>   line 592, in **call**
>       self.build(input_shapes[0])
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py",
>   line 461, in build
>       self.cell.build(step_input_shape)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\recurrent.py",
>   line 1838, in build
>       constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\legacy\interfaces.py",
>   line 91, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py",
>   line 416, in add_weight
>       constraint=constraint)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
>   line 395, in variable
>       v = tf.Variable(value, dtype=tf.as_dtype(dtype), name=name)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py",
>   line 235, in **init**
>       constraint=constraint)
>
> File
>   "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\variables.py",
>   line 356, in _init_from_args
>       "initializer." % name)

Comment: Please share the stack trace.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Great to see you again. I added the stack trace of the error.

Comment: As it is a dtype problem as it seems. The input and target data is both float64. Could that be the error? In the description, tensor or float32 is accepted if no other dtype is given. I will try to convert both to float32 and get back with the results

Comment: Is this line really like this in your code? `model.add(Masking(mask_value=666, input_shape=X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))` (it seems the input shape should be `(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])` instead.

Comment: No, you are right. That was a copy+past error. It is correct in brackets in the original code. Thanks. Edited now in the main text

Comment: Using float32 did not change the error.

Comment: Does it work without the masking layer?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. (shape determined now in LSTM layer).

Comment: What is the type of the var 'Dropout'? Are we sure dropout works with masking? (I don't know)

Comment: Dropout is just an float. But I also tried it without dropout (I guess it is either than set to 0 or false on default). But I guess dropout should also work with masking. But it is a good question if the masking values are integrated in the dropout or not included. But I would say that is a whole new discussion :-)

Comment: Well... I can't find anything wrong with the code :(

Comment: That is good and bad news at the same time :-). It was working before but at that time the Target was completely wrong in dimension. I will roll it back and see what changed. Thanks so far for your help. If I find something I will add it to this thread. Have a nice evening.

Comment: Maybe you could restart your python kernel entirely... sometimes I get very weird bugs that are solved like this. (Not sure why, but often it starts when I interrupt some code in the middle)

Comment: NOOOOOOWAYYY. That was the issue. Dear Lord. Everyday we learn. Thank you so much. I would have been stuck for ever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution, in this case, was to restart the Kernel. 
Thanks to  Daniel Möller